# SQL server update query to add totals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

- The first record Amount and TotalAmount are same
- In the second record Amount is added from first row and current and TotalAmount is added
- And so on....

Now if I update the second row from 1.25 to 2, then the TotalAmount for all subsequent records should be changed.

I need an update query for this.
I have seq_no and row no as reference and field Type is the reference

[image]

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store computed values like that. Too high risk for data inconsistency. If you really, really need to do it, handle it with triggers.

Comment: You should store only Amount data. TotalAmount should not be stored since it can calculated on the fly.

Comment: @Girish Jarlh's comment cannot be emphasized enough. **This is horrible database design** and you are in for much more difficulties in the future. Change to a properly normalized design structure **now**.

Comment: Should the totals be per type or for every row in the table independent of the type column?

Comment: @Jan Doggen, Thank you Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should create a view or stored procedure that performs a running total, this is an example of one method using a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    Type,
    Amount , 
    Total = 
    (
           SELECT SUM(Amount) 
           FROM SomeTable B 
           WHERE B.Type=A.Type AND B.RowNum <= A.RowNum
    )
FROM SomeTable A
```

This is just one method (not necessarily the best). I would suggest you google 'Running totals in SQL' and familiarise yourself with the explanation of this and other methods their pros, cons and performance implications of each.
One question, what version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use row number as reference than you can try following query but storing totals in table is bad idea as mentioned in comment:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(   
    Amount float,
    TotalAmount float,
    Rownum int
)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1.25,1.25,1),(1.25,2.50,2),(10,12.50,3)

DECLARE @PreviousAmount AS FLOAT
SELECT @PreviousAmount = Amount FROM @Temp WHERE Rownum=1

DECLARE @NewAmount AS FLOAT = 2

UPDATE @Temp SET TotalAmount = TotalAmount - @PreviousAmount WHERE Rownum>=1
UPDATE @Temp SET Amount=@NewAmount, TotalAmount = TotalAmount + @NewAmount WHERE Rownum=1
UPDATE @Temp SET TotalAmount = TotalAmount + @NewAmount WHERE Rownum>1

SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use triggers(which is not recommended).you can use this:

```
create trigger trigger_name
for update
 as

declare @count int= (select count(*) from table)
declare @a int =1


while(@a<@count)
begin
update table
set total_amount=(select amount from table where row_number=@a) + (select  amount from table           where row_number=@a-1 )
 where row_number!=1
 set @a=@a+1
 end

 Go
```

Comment: I'd avoid using a trigger like others have already mentioned I'd also avoid using a while loop!